# How to order related field by its foreign key fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

Let's assume I have three model like below;

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    gp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    won = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    drawn = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lose = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gf = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ga = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gd = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pts = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stats = models.ForeignKey(Stats)

class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
```

And, this is my serializer for Group Model

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    teams = TeamSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

However, I want to order the teams according to pts and gd fields of their stats. I tried to add `order_with_respect_to='stats'` to the Team model and `ordering = ['pts', 'gd']` to the Stats Model but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stats = models.ForeignKey(Stats)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['stats__pts', 'stats__gd']
```

Comment: yeah that worked I just add a "-" sign for descending order thank youu